# Passing/Getting the session("userid") on login page. IN virtual studio -> vb

Tags: asp.net

Passing/Getting the session("userid") on login page. IN virtual studio -> vb

How can get with the vs login box ??

Comment: Could you elaborate your question a little more?

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET, the normal methodology is to use the login control. YOu can set up, in the web.config file, to redirect to the page with this control whenever a user is not logged in.

The fact you are sending things via session suggests you are either using ASP or you are still caught in the ASP paradigm, as there is no reason to take control of this part of your application. Even if you have a completely different methodology for login, you can create a custom provider and still use the underlying built in bits. Why reinvent the wheel when you don't have to.

I am not sure what you mean by the VS login box, however.

Here is a link to an MSDN article on using the login control. Perhaps it will help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx